# Pattern Day Trade Rule

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-exchanges, regulation

I'm new to trading and to play around with I will open a small account with $1,500. The problem with this that I want to be a quite active trader,so I can make more profit from this small amount.
 But the problem is Pattern Day Trade Rule.From finra.org

> The rules adopt the term "pattern day trader," which includes any margin customer that day trades (buys then sells or sells short then buys the same security on the same day) four or more times in five business days, provided the number of day trades are more than six percent of the customer's total trading activity for that same five-day period. - See more at: http://www.finra.org/investors/day-trading-margin-requirements-know-rules#sthash.1Qj9Gkbd.dpuf

I wanted to ask if selling and buying the same stock is 1 or 2 trades? I mean is entering a position or exiting is considered as a trade? Or a trade is a combination of entering and exiting? Because I'm quite confused if I will be able to swing trade a couple times week for example Will I be able to buy a stock lets say on Monday and sell it on Tuesday and buy it again on lets say Thursday and sell it on Friday?

Comment: Will you be trading in the United States? You didn't specify a country but your profile indicates another one.

Comment: I'm living in Lithuania but will be trading only U.S stocks

Comment: Your link says you need to have at least $25000 equity to trade this way, so you would not be allower to trade with just $1500. Does your country allow trading in CFDs? And have you considered other short term trading instead of day trading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest following your quote and having a read of the web page supplied, that `buys then sells` or `sells short then buys` (the same security on the same day) four or more times in five business days, ...

So it is a two way transaction that counts as 'one'.